# How to add ms bot in kaizala

Tags: botframework, azure-bot-service, direct-line-botframework, kaizala

I am new to kaizala. Currently, the kaizala is not supported as a channel in ms bot. Just wondering if i can use the directline api but not sure on the kaizala part.

Please help/guide me on this, especially on the kaizala part what exactly I have to do to integrate ms bot with kaizala if somebody have tried this before.

Answer (score 0):

There are a variety of adapters you can use as a reference for building a Kaizala adapter of your own. I don't know which SDK you are using, but if you check out the [BotBuilder-Samples](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples) repo and navigate to the samples folder you will see examples of how to use some of the official adapters. Once you know what you are looking for you can navigate to the SDK repos (for ex: https://github.com/Microsoft/botbuilder-js) and find the adapter code.

Another source is the [BotBuilder-Community](https://github.com/BotBuilderCommunity) repo which has examples of non-official adapters that you can also reference, organized by SDK.

All of these should provide an understanding of how to go about building what you need. I haven't researched Kaizala, at all, but if they provide APIs for connecting to and interacting with their service, then you will want to integrate that into the adapter.

Hope of help!